# How to refresh contents in NanoGallery jQuery Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nanogallery

I want to be able to remove the album contents from my div when pressing a button. Something like $("#myDiv").html(""), so the gallery is removed from the DOM and then I am able to recreate the gallery in the same div, but with a different data source array when clicking another button.

Right now I have a function that creates the nanoGallery and I call it when the user clicks on a button, then when the user clicks another button I need to remove the nanoGallery and recreate it with different data.

The code that is not working right now:

```
function createAlbum()
{
    // This object has a different array every time button is clicked!
    var pics = currentOrder["vehicle-pictures"];

    $("#repairPictures").nanoGallery({
        items                 : pics,
        colorSchemeViewer     : 'light',
        photoset              : 'none',
        viewerDisplayLogo     : true,
        thumbnailLazyLoad     : true,
        thumbnailLabel        : { display: true, position: 'overImageOnBottom', titleMaxLength: 35 },
        colorScheme           : { thumbnail:{ labelBackground: '#444 !important' } }, 
        locationHash          : false,
        thumbnailHoverEffect  :'borderLighter,imageScaleIn80'
    });
}
```

Then to remove it...

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
function cleanAlbum()
{
    $("#repairPictures").html("");
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

BTW, the $("#myDiv").html("") approach is just an example, if you know a better way to remove the gallery html from the div, please feel free to suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove album from DOM, use: `$('#yourElement').nanoGallery('destroy');`, but you can set new items for nanoGallery and just do `$('#yourElement').nanoGallery('reload');`

Comment: Awesome answer!  Thanks very much, worked like a charm :)